# Images not showing after about 1 day of upload with editors (ckeditor)

Tags: django, image, digital-ocean, ckeditor4.x, digital-ocean-spaces

I host my files on Digitalocean space. Almost everything works fine. The only issue is that I am unable to see images uploaded with editors for instance ckeditor after about a day of upload. This does show at first but fail to display by second day.

When I tried to preview the image to ascertain what is wrong, I encountered this kind of error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code> 
<RequestId>txgjk006000a4ca-47ce82d-nyc3bkkhv**""**</RequestId>
<HostId>47ce82d-***********zg02</HostId>
</Error>
```

Note: I replaced some things with ****.

I've tried what I could do eg changing permission but all to no avail.

Other images uploaded through IMG tags are displaying properly.

The app is a django app.

Kindly help.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a Django issue to be honest. It's something in your DigitalOcean config.

Comment: Thanks for the comment  somecallitblues. My thought as well, but there isn't really much config in digital ocean space. I've tried changing it from private to public but that didn't solve the problem. I guess it's an issue with expiration but how would that be since the file uploaded through HTML tags are working fine but the issue is with editors? I've also checked my settings.py if I've made mistake but couldn't find any mistake. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by enabling CDN, change the setting to public instead of privates, change all the files to public recursively and set DEFAULT_ACL to 'public-read'. Everything now works fine